# Exponentiation of a floating number

Tags: precision, exponentiation

I am trying to print the exact exponentiation of a floating number but i failed to print the digits of the exponentiation after 5 decimal digits. What should be done in order to get rest of the digits?

Example: 1.0100 ^ 12 = 1.126825030131969720661201
But i only managed to print 1.12863 by using simple pow() function. Can anyone help if i need to use strings or something else and how?

```
while(cin >> r >> n)
{
    long double ans = pow(r, n);
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: Floats only have about 7 decimal digits' worth of precision. This is behaving as expected (though maybe not as desired).

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/ ?

Comment: I came to know about setprecisions. but extending upto 30 or 40 digits after the decimal point can't be earned. How to solve this?